# Deduce the Hölder Inequality

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, inequality, holder-inequality

> If $f, g$ are two functions $\geq 0$ in an interval $I$ such that the
> integrals $\int_I f(t) d t$ and $\int_I g(t) d t$ are convergent, the
> integral $\int_I(f(t))^\alpha(g(t))^{1-\alpha} d t$ is convergent and
> we have $$ \int_I(f(t))^\alpha(g(t))^{1-\alpha} d t \leq a \int_I f(t)
> d t+b \int_I g(t) d t . $$ Deduce the Hölder inequality $$
>  \int_I(f(t))^\alpha(g(t))^{1-\alpha} d t \leq\left(\int_I f(t) d
>  t\right)^\alpha\left(\int_I g(t) d t\right)^{1-\alpha} $$

My attempt: By Young Inequality we know that for $0 \leq \alpha \leq 1$, we have
$$x^{\alpha} y^{1- \alpha} \leq ax + by,
$$where $a + b = 1$.
Thus if we set $x = f(t)$ and $y=g(t)$, then we get
$$ f(t)^{\alpha}g(t)^{1-\alpha} \leq af(t) + bg(t).
$$
If we integrate over $I$, we get the wanted inequality.
I don't see how to proceed to get the Hölder inequality now.

Comment: This might work: Let $h > 0$. replace $f$ by $hf$, $g$ by $g/h$. Now minimize the resulting inequality over $h > 0$.

Comment: so you want to say that I have to consider $(hf)^{\alpha}(g/h)^{1-\alpha} \leq ahf + bg/h$?

Comment: integrate that then optimize. Actually,  you want the $h$s to cancel on the left, so maybe this isn't the way to go

Comment: Hmm ok, I see...

Comment: There is a Terry Tao blog post on this. He calls it an "amplification" of an inequality, using symmetry. The blog post is called "Amplification, arbitrage and the tensor power trick".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is maybe easier to see, if we define $\newcommand{\norm}[1]{\left\lVert#1\right\rVert}$
$$
\norm{f}_p = \left( \int_{I} |f(t)|^{p} \, dt \right)^{1/p}
$$
and $p, q$ such that $\alpha = 1/p$ and $1-\alpha = 1/q$.

Furthermore, by replacing $f$ by $f^{p}$ and $g$ by $g^{q}$, the inequality can be rewritten in simpler form.

Finally, by multiplying by suitable constants, we may assume that $\norm{f}_p = 1$ and $\norm{g}_q = 1$ and deduce that:
\begin{equation}
\int_{I} f(t) g(t) \, dt \leq 
a \norm{f}_p^{p} + b \norm{g}_q^{q} = 1
= \norm{f}_p \norm{g}_q
\tag{1}
\end{equation}

**Remark.** I basically just rewrote everything into a more standard form using norms and these substitutions. From which Hölder's inequality clearly follows. Replacing $f^{p}$ by $f$ and $g^{q}$ by $g$ and substituting back $\alpha$ in (1) we get Hölder's inequality in the form it was written in the question.

Answer (score 0):

This is somewhat using a sledgehammer to crack a nut, but you can use something called the "[weighted AM-GM inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means#Weighted_AM%E2%80%93GM_inequality)" and the result drops out.

$$
{1\over 1-\alpha+\alpha}
\left(
\alpha\left(\int f\right)^\alpha+
(1-\alpha)
\left(\int g\right)^{1-\alpha}\right)\geq
\sqrt[1-\alpha+\alpha]{
\left(\int f\right)^\alpha\left(\int g\right)^{1-\alpha}
}
$$
The $1-\alpha+\alpha$ in the above is just $1$, and both the division and the root are redundant, so
$$
\alpha
\left(
\int f\right)^\alpha+
(1-\alpha)
\left(\int g\right)^{1-\alpha}\geq
\left(\int f\right)^\alpha\left(\int g\right)^{1-\alpha}
$$